# counting unique ids for occurences in condition

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a df which has column `change`, which has two types BR and NBR and `id`, every id is unique

I am trying to calculate these metrics:

cases of ids with atleast one instance where change = 'BR'

cases of ids with atleast one instance where change = 'NBR'

cases of ids where all changes = 'BR'

cases of ids where all changes = 'NBR'

Here is my sample df:

```
data = {
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6],
    'change': ['BR', 'NBR', 'BR', 'NBR', 'BR', 'BR', 'BR', 'NBR', 'NBR', 'BR']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The expected output:

```
cases of ids with atleast one instance where change = 'BR' = 5
cases of ids with atleast one instance where change = 'NBR' = 3
cases of ids where all changes = 'BR' = 3
cases of ids where all changes = 'NBR'= 1
```

I am trying to calculate these metrics but running into some error as the code I have written seems to be wrong, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain better and show sample of your data. Which field needs to be unique? the ID?

Comment: yes the id is unique, basically the frameworks means counting the id's

Comment: Kindly show a snippet of your dataframe along with the expected output.

Comment: My df is kindly there please check, i added the expected output( which would be wrong since i have many rows in my df)

Comment: Your code for 'framework*' and 'all*' is the same. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `nunique()` for the first case:

```
df.groupby('change')['id'].nunique()
```

Returning:

```
change
BR     5
NBR    3
```

As for the second logic, use:

```
df[df.groupby('id')['change'].transform('nunique') == 1].drop_duplicates()['change'].value_counts()
```

Returning:

```
BR     3
NBR    1
```

Comment: The first one works perfectly the second gives me a type error: unhashable type dict. I am not sure why

Comment: @Celius solution above works fine!

Comment: Do you know what could be the possible cause for my error?

Comment: @gtomer It might be working fine for you, but it looks like OP is encountering an issue.

Comment: OP is encountering an issue because their MVE is not correctly reflected. I have run this code on what OP shares as input data and there are no errors, so the errors are coming from somewhere else in the code, or the variables are not correctly defined/used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
frameworks_BR = df[df['change'] == 'BR']['id'].nunique()
frameworks_NBR = df[df['change'] == 'NBR']['id'].nunique()
```

Please explain what you expect with the "all_*" parameters

Comment: So I have two columns, id is unique, change has two values BR and NBR. I need to calculate the count of ids for 4 cases, one where there is atleast one BR present within the row, same for NBR. Then count ids where all rows have change =BR then same for change =NBR

Comment: The all is just a keyword I am using to signify the count, it is not related to the code in any way, i mentioned it as a notation where i want to store the count

Comment: Consider using nunique instead of `len(pd.Series.unique())`